# Multiple instances of image rotate plugin, jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, rotation

I would like to have multiple images rotate, or gyrate, or spin, whatever the term best describes the 2D image rotate, from the same document.

The jquery plugin that does this for one image is: http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples

Although the example page shows many instances of rotating images, these are loaded from iframes. Meaning, each rotating image is the portion of another document shown through iframe.

I am trying to rotate different images, at different speeds, and in different angles and it is not working.

For example, for two images I used code

```
var angle = 0;

    setInterval(function(){
      angle+=3;
     jQuery(".process-1").rotate(angle);
},50);
setInterval(function(){
      angle-=3;
     jQuery(".process-2").rotate(angle);
},30);
```

Thank you

Comment: You're going to have to explain yourself better and show your code.  [The example page](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples) is working fine on multiple images.

Comment: Post code please. We have no idea where you're running into issues.

Comment: See the edits to my answer which contain your actual code with the fix applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be working fine on multiple images.  You did not explain what you wanted, but here is the code for spinning three images...

http://jsfiddle.net/RwEme/603/

```
var rotation = function (){
   $("#image, #image2, #image3").rotate({
      angle:0, 
      animateTo:360, 
      callback: rotation,
      easing: function (x,t,b,c,d){        // t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c: change In value, d: duration
          return c*(t/d)+b;
      }
   });
}
rotation();
```

HTML:

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" id="image"/>
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" id="image2"/>
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" id="image3"/>​
```

---

**EDIT:**

Here is another working demo based on edits to the OP.

http://jsfiddle.net/RwEme/604/

It wasn't working because you're trying to use the same variable (`angle`) for two different things.

```
var angle = 0,
    angle2 = 0;

setInterval(function() {
      angle += 3;
     $("#image").rotate(angle);
},80);
setInterval(function() {
      angle2 -= 3;
     $("#image2").rotate(angle2);
},20);​
```

Comment: Sorry, got a bit worked up... your second solution worked. THANK YOU

Comment: @IberoMedia, You're very welcome.  Keep in mind that I initially answered it before you posted any of your code.

Comment: Your solution works well. One comment I have though is that each rotating image adds a variable to the global namespace. To prevent this pollution you can wrap each animation in a function and call that. It's a little cleaner. See my solution for an example.

Comment: @koenp, regarding "pollution", there's a lot fewer lines of code in mine.  And there's not much difference between declaring `angle` two different times within two functions, or just declaring two unique variables.

Comment: Yes, yours is shorter and if you like short you should go with it. Just saying that *IF* you want to prevent to add stuff to the global JavaScript namespace you can wrap them in function calls, or one big function call around your code. Global namespace pollution is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

They do work with rotated animation. You have to make sure that you wrap each rotate in a different function so the scope of the `angle` variable is limited to that function. Otherwise both animations share the same variable which will not work. Here's a working jsfiddle with two of them:

http://jsfiddle.net/YKj5D/215/

I use this code to start the animations

```
(function() {
  var angle = 0;
  setInterval(function(){
      angle+=3;
     $("#image3").rotate(angle);
  },50);
}​)();

(function() {
  var angle = 0;
  setInterval(function(){
      angle+=10;
     $("#image4").rotate(angle);
  },50);
})();
​
​
```